# How to create a function to send emails formatting html message with a variable list?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a function in django to send my HTML email templates with certain variables.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import get_connection
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from otr import settings


def send_email(subject, email_template, recipient, username, password, variable_list):
    html_message = render_to_string(email_template, {'context': 'values'})

    for variable in variable_list:
        html_message.format(variable)

    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
    recipient = recipient

    with get_connection(
            host=settings.EMAIL_HOST,
            port=settings.EMAIL_PORT,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            use_tls=True
    ) as connection:
        send_mail(subject, plain_message, 'Me', [recipient], fail_silently=False,
                  html_message=html_message, connection=connection)
```

Then I want to call this function to be used in different django views like:

```
subject = "My subject"
email_template = "emails/followup_email.html"
recipient = queryset.customer_email
username = username_variable
password = password_variable
customer_name = "Bob"
dear_user = "my_name"
phone_number = "1111111111"
sincerely_user = "my_name"
variable_list = [customer_name, dear_user, phone_number, sincerely_user]

send_email(subject, email_template, recipient, username, password, variable_list)
```

I keep getting "Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple", so I am guessing I can't do a for loop in this way to format the HTML email with a list of variables. Does anyone know how to accomplish this a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct `Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple` error you get is because of the for loop in `send_email` function. Replace those two lines with -

```py
html_message.format(*variable_list)
```

Note: The `html_message` string should contain same number of placeholders `{}` as the number of items in `variable_list` i.e., `4` in this case for `format` to work correctly.